# Existe una herramienta que te devuelva las llamadas a microservicios de una web?

Tags: post, get

Me gustaría hacer un análisis de una web que realiza muchas llamadas a microservicios y quisiera saber si existe alguna herramienta que te muestre esto sin necesidad de utilizar el "Network" de la consola de depuración del navegador.

Comment: puedes utilizar la herramienta [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), hay bastantes tutoriales en internet (https://www.codementor.io/@aydindev/introduction-to-using-fiddler-for-debug-http-s-requests-djf60hjsf)

Comment: Este sitio es para aclaracion de dudas sobre codificacion asi que lo mas probable es que sea eliminada tu pregunta.